# Is there a Japanese word or phrase for the chemistry in a relationship?

Tags: words, phrase-requests, word-requests

Is there a Japanese word or phrase for the chemistry in a relationship?

And by "relationship", I don't mean a strictly romantic one. It could be the chemistry between best friends, or even the lack of chemistry when meeting someone new and feeling like the two of you don't click.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that the most versatile counterpart would be 「相性{あいしょう}」.  It can be used in any kind of interpersonal relationships including romantic ones.

We say:

> 「(Person A) + **と** + (Peson B) + **は** + 相性がいい。」 or
>
> 「(Person A) + **と** + (Peson B) + **は** + 相性が悪{わる}い。」

Every once in a while, you will encounter the word 「ケミストリー」, but it is not very common at all.